# Gnome's Software ignores apt's "kept-back" package status

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

## Problem description

The application *Software* (that is, Gnome Software 41.5) shows available updates, while `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` finds no updates, apart from some kept-back packages:

[image]

Output of terminal:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease               
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                
Hit:5 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease  
Hit:6 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  alsa-ucm-conf gnome-remote-desktop update-notifier update-notifier-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

```
apt-cache policy alsa-ucm-conf
alsa-ucm-conf:
  Installed: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.2 500 (phased 70%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

```
sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
```

## Solutions tried

- I ran `dpkg --configure -a` (maybe some weird update failure problem?), without luck.
- I changed the Updates download server from my local server to *Main server* (maybe updates are yet to be pushed to the former, while *Software* uses *Main server*?), without luck.

The installation (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) is fairly new (a week old) and has been updated without any freak occurrences yet.

Why does this happen? Do I have to expect issues after pressing *Software*'s Update button, which seems to conflict `apt`'s and therefore `dpkg`'s assessment?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1450945/edit) to show the complete output of `apt cache policy alsa-ucm-conf` and of `sudo snap refresh`.

Comment: Done. AFAIK, the apt-cache output seems alright

Comment: Ok, I found the "OS Updates" label in _Software_ to be clickable to reveal packages which "OS Updates" is concerned with.  
It turns out that these packages match exactly those kept back during `apt upgrade`.  
I guess this implies that _Software_ does not care / correctly pay respect to packages who are to be kept back. Don't know if this is wanted or a bug.

Comment: Both apt and Update Manager and Ubuntu Software show updates, including phased (kept back) updates, since they all get their information from the same source. Your `apt cache policy` output clearly shows phasing "`(phased 70%)`."

Comment: Are you able to install held back packages through GNOME Software? I am not, and so it is pretty annoying that they show up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comment, after getting capable to correctly use the GUI of GNOME's *Software*, it turns out that its announced “OS Updates” are the same packages which are kept back by `apt`.
As @user535733 correctly commented, my original question (are `apt` and *Software* in some fundamental disagreement) is technically solved.

Yet, two open points emerge/remain:

- Why does *Software* ignore phasing? Is this wanted or a bug?

  - My best guess would be that people who use *Software* at all are wishing for a simple and risk-minimizing OS experience, which would be somewhat contradicted by throwing out phased package introductions.
- Where do the other packages below "OS Updates" come from?
  `snap refresh` and `flatpak update` does not show any upgrades either.

I guess these points are overly tangential to the original question, so that I would close it and potentially repost these two points after some further examination.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, some packages the very same as you, although with some differences (for example `alsa-ucm-conf` was 80% phased for me) and I solved (reiterating) following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1107334/apt-says-packages-have-been-kept-back-what-to-do):

`sudo apt list --upgradable` to check which packages are eligible for update

and then `sudo apt install alsa-ucm-conf` and similar for any other package